# Unknown provider: HomeServiceProvider <- HomeService

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Project Architecture:

```
-> public/modules/core/services/home.client.service.js
-> public/modules/core/controllers/home.client.controller.js
-> public/modules/core/controllers/header.client.controller.js
-> public/modules/core/views/header.client.view.html
-> public/modules/core/views/home.client.view.html
```

I am trying to inject home.client.service into home.client.controller.js

The following code:

```
angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'HomeService',
    function($scope, $q, Authentication, HomeService) {
```

Returns:

```
Unknown provider: HomeServiceProvider <- HomeService
```

Whereas:

```
angular.module('core',[]).controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'HomeService',
    function($scope, $q, Authentication, HomeService) {
```

Returns:

```
Argument 'HeaderController' is not a function, got undefined
```

header.client.controller.js looks like:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('core').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'Menus',
function($scope, Authentication, Menus) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;
    $scope.menu = Menus.getMenu('topbar');

    $scope.toggleCollapsibleMenu = function() {
        $scope.isCollapsed = !$scope.isCollapsed;
    };

    // Collapsing the menu after navigation
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
        $scope.isCollapsed = false;
    });
}
]);
```

home.client.service is:

```
angular.module('core').service('HomeService', function($http) {

function get(n,idc,cluster,type){
  //Return a promise
  return $http.post('url/search?idc=' + idc + '&type=' + type + 'cluster=' + cluster , n);
}

return {
  get: get
}

});
```

Can anyone help me correctly inject my service into my controller?

Comment: First there is no HeaderController here or at least we don't see it. Second have you included the HomeService js file to index,html?

Comment: home.client.view.html contains:

<section  data-ng-controller="HomeController">

Comment: As does header.client.view.html

Comment: can you check if you import your service js file before your module js file inside your html file?

Comment: The only thing I import is : `<section data-ng-controller="HomeController">`

Comment: @Corbin Have you imported your HomeService.js file like this:  <script src="your_path_to_services_folder/HomeService.js"></script> in your index.html page

Comment: @vbouk - No I haven't, would I include this in the view?

Comment: @Corbin not in the view. in the index.html file. I suppose you have one

Answer (score 0):

You need the string `'$q'` in your array as well.

Like this:

```
    angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', 
          ['$scope', '$q', 'Authentication', 'HomeService',
          function($scope, $q, Authentication, HomeService) {
```

Comment: And you might consider dropping the manual dependency injection annotations and adding [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to your build pipeline to prevent this class of errors from ever happening again.

Comment: Anyway it will still throw `Unknown provider: HomeServiceProvider <- HomeService`, because this indeed doesn't resolve problem, only typo. -1

Comment: @gefei - I still get 'Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: HomeServiceProvider <- HomeService'

Comment: @Corbin where did you define your HomeService? You need to add the module to the definition of your 'core' module: angular.module('core', [<name of modules core is depedent of>]. See docu here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

Comment: @gefei - As you can see I try and define it in home.client.controller.js

Comment: @Corbin can you show the code where you defined HomeService?

Comment: angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$q', 'Authentication', 'HomeService',
    function($scope, $q, Authentication, HomeService) {

Comment: @Corbin that code defines HomeController. What code defines HomeService?

Comment: @gefei - Updated question to include home.client.service.js

Comment: @Corbin try `angular.module('core', []) ...`

Comment: As you can see in the original question, I already tried this initially and received: `Argument 'HeaderController' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: @gefei - I have been stuck on this stupid error for 3 hours!

Comment: "HomeController is not a function" sounds like there is some syntax error in the definition of HomeController. Does your IDE show any errors?

Comment: @gefei - I'm using Notepad++ and the error is `'HeaderController' is not a function`

Comment: and when I don't try to inject the HomeService in it works fine!

Comment: I am pretty sure there is some syntax error in HeaderController. I would check it

Comment: header.client.controller.js is in the question - I can't see any issue with it, can you?